# while using angular grid ,I assigned the typeof RouData to 'any' since im getting from the api,but the compiler says,

Tags: typescript

ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:17:13 - error TS2693: 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

rowData = any;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, its wrong syntax. The below snippet might help:

```
rowData: any[]=[];
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: First of all a very thanks for answering my question,infact this is my first question.And a small correction,rowData: any=[];

Comment: Great to know that it was helpful to you